# Losing my $_GET variable upon form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, url, get

I'm creating a small application which allows potential employees to list references. The listed references receive an email containing a `URL` with a unique string at the end.

(Example: `www.the-address.com?url=503241c65b8fe4_07914393`). The reference then follows this unique `URL` to upload a letter in the employee's behalf.

But every time any form is submitted, the random string part of the URL disappears

(Example:   `www.the-address.com?url=`).

I don't understand why this would happen, since I submit the form like this:

```
<form action="upload_letter.php?url="' . $url . '" id="form_id" method="POST">;
```

Where `$url =  $_GET['url']`.

Any generic reasons this would happen? I can provide more code, if needed.

Comment: You should just generate a hidden input and set the value to $url, then you can use $_REQUEST

Comment: Where is $url being assigned a value?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to have the querystring? Why not put those values in a few `<input type="hidden" />`s?

Comment: I really think you do not have a defined value for $url. Although you are using method="POST", it should not alter your URL in anyway.  Try to echo $url and verify that a vale is being attached.

Comment: The problem is that the action attribute gets closed even before the value right at `url="`, there's just one too many `"`.

Comment: try looking at the source of your page and you'll see the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$data = array('url' => $url);

?>
<form action="upload_letter.php?<?php echo http_build_query($data) ?>" id="form_id" method="POST">
```

Or you can just add the URL as a hidden `<input>`

```
<form action="upload_letter.php" id="form_id" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo htmlentities($url); ?>">
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

Then you can access URL via `$_POST['url']`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @WolfgangStengel! I usually go with the short tags, but `htmlentities()` is the right way to go there.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have the code like you write, you're closing the `action` attribute prematurely with the second `"` character. Try this instead:

```
echo '<form action="upload_letter.php?url='.urlencode($url).'" id="form_id" method="POST">';
```

The way you have it would end up as HTML like:

```
<form action="upload_letter.php?url="google.de" id="form_id"...>
```

With google.de outside the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Change `method="POST"` to `method="GET"`

Comment: This won't change anything, forms submit using POST still may have GET params.

Comment: Further parameters in the form will overwrite ?url.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is what you wrote on your PHP file: it is wrong. No ";" at the end of an HTML line, and you can't concatenate strings with "." in HTML. You must open the PHP tag and write PHP code inside. For example:

```
<form action="upload_letter.php?url=<?php echo $url; ?>" id="form_id" method="POST">
```

But you can also use echo like Wolfgang answer

Comment: This still has the problem with the second `"` closing the `action` attribute too soon.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I didn't remove `"` from copy and paste. Edited

Answer (score -1):

Probably $url is empty or undefined.
Check the HTML code to see if its written into the form's action.

Answer (score -2):

why you put single quotes around:

```
 . $url .
```

?

EDIT: Another way to say this:
Are you sure you're on a `<?php ?>` tag?

Comment: @Wolfgang Stengel ...and yours is not a comment